# Inversing a boolean based on a variable

Tags: javascript

Say for ***example*** I have a sorting function but I want to reverse it based on another variable.

**What I know**

- `if` `else`
- ternary `?`

I was wondering if there was some kind of cool trick like `(true && "return this")` or `!!(+num % 2)` kind of stuff.

Example:

```js
var array = [3,5,2,1,7,8,10];
var reverse = true;

array.sort( function(a,b) {
  return a < b // somehow use reverse to sort it reverse order
});
```

**Addendum**

While David's answer was the one I was looking for in response to my question. This is what I think would be appropriate if I was looking to conditionally sort: Short circuiting.

```js
var array = [3,5,2,1,7,8,10];
var reverse = true;

function number_sort(a,b) {
 return a > b ;
}


(array.sort(number_sort) && reverse && array.reverse());

console.log(array);

reverse = false;

(array.sort(number_sort) && reverse && array.reverse());

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Why not use the `reverse` array method?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's just an example. I could use it for `localeCompare` or any other type of matching

Comment: Note that the `sort` callback should return a value <0, 0 or >0 though, not `true` or `false`.

Comment: @deceze that's true, just couldn't really think of any other examples :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you're just returning a boolean from your `sort`, you could return the boolean value of whether or not your boolean matches your `reverse` variable:

```
array.sort( function(a,b) {
  return a < b == reverse
});
```

Comment: ahh, I think this was what I was looking for. Simple and one lined. Will mark when can

Comment: Issue is that Array.prototype.sort() expects an optional function that must return an int, not a boolean.

Comment: @sp00m yeah it was just an example, I was thinking of filter lol

Comment: @A.Lau, well, better ask for your real-world case next time, as some native functions may already exist and suit your needs (such as Array.prototype.reverse() if your question were really about sorting) ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a variable `asc`, which could have the value `true` for ascending sorting or `false` for descending sorting. Then use the value of `asc` as factor, if given or use `-1` for descending sorting.

The factor `-1` reverses the sort order as needed for the sort function.

```js
var array = [3, 5, 2, 1, 7, 8, 10],
    asc = false;

array.sort(function(a, b) { return (asc || -1) * (a - b); });
console.log(array);

asc = true;
array.sort(function(a, b) { return (asc || -1) * (a - b); });
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Version with a closure over the sort order

```js
var sortFn = function (asc) {
       return function(a, b) {
           return (asc || -1) * (a - b);
       };
    },
    array = [3, 5, 2, 1, 7, 8, 10];

array.sort(sortFn(false)); // desc
console.log(array);

array.sort(sortFn(true));  // asc
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would conditionally choose the sort function:

```
array.sort(reverse
  ? (a, b) => a - b
  : (a, b) => b - a
);
```

Advantage is that condition is evaluated only once instead of for every item.

Otherwise, quite obvious:

```
array.sort(...);
if (reverse) {
  array.reverse();
}
```

Comment: Ahh, your answer made me short-circuiting. This is what I was looking for this `(array.sort(number_sort) && false && array.reverse());`

Comment: @A.Lau In this case, `array.reverse()` won't ever be called as JS short-circuits boolean operators.

Comment: that's the point. If I want it reversed, then reverse will be true, thus it will reverse it at the very end. If I don't, then reverse won't ever be called. And since Javascript mutates the object, this does what I want it to do. I +1'd for giving me that reminder

Comment: @A.Lau Ah ok, `false` actually is `reverse` :) Glad I could help! Note that `sort` indeed mutates the object, but `filter` or `concat` doesn't for example though. Depends on the function :)

Comment: which then David's answer would be the most appropriate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a ternary operator:

```
var array = [3,5,2,1,7,8,10];
var reverse = true;

array.sort( function(a,b) {
  return reverse ? (a > b) : (a < b)
});
```